# Unable to login into Ubuntu Server after upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, login, 20.04

Since the update I did today I am unable to login into my server. I did an upgrade using this [tutorial](https://www.linuxtechi.com/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-ubuntu-20-04-lts/). The upgrade process executed successful but after an reboot I am now able to login to my machine.
The first problem was that an entry in the fstab was corrupt (the entry for the raid cluster). I booted into recovery and commented this entry out. After this I came to the login screen.
But the behavior is now the following:

- There is a line saying "Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS tty1"
- "nas login:" I enter my username (then I hit enter)
- after this nothing happens
- normally I would expect "Password:" to be shown
- if i type my password, I see my password in clear text

This is not as it should be. Can someone please help me fixing this problem?

When booting into rescue mode, the root shell says something like: failed to execute /bin/bash: No such file or directory.